# laravel envoy on multiple server

Tags: laravel, laravel-envoy

I seem to misunderstand somethings from the envoy docs.

If I have 10 php servers and I have some tasks that should delete some files from all the servers
and I have this simplified code:

```
@servers(['web-1' => '1.1.1.1', 'web-2' => '1.1.1.2','web-3'=>'1.1.1.3'])

@task('remove-image', ['on' => ['web-1', 'web-2','web-3']])
    rm /var/www/html/example.jpg
@endtask
```

how does laravel will run the command on other servers? I didnt gave it any access or anything

Comment: `//you get the idea` Not really :/ I have no idea how you're trying to achieve this.

Comment: @devk sorry about that, I updated the code, but my question has nothing to do with the task, but rather how envoy is running the task on other servers without giving it ssh access